# Adding a .S file to the linux kernel code

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel

I'm trying to add a new assembly (.S) file to the Linux kernel.
It may be a dumb question, but I can't seem to find how and where to add such files to the make files. I've looked at code examples of current .S files, but I can't find where they are assembled and linked to the vmlinux binary.

Any hints would be appericiated.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not really familiar with this stuff (which is why I'm not going to provide an answer), but if you know where the .s files reside, is it possible the makefile is referencing the entire folder, so you could just put your code in that folder, or add a unique folder to your makefile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the corresponding `.o` result to some rule. There are implicit rules for the `.S` -> `.o` translation.

Comment: Works perfectly! (as long as I don't have .c and .S files with the same name)

Answer (score 1):

look in

```
arch/i386/boot
```

and it's included Makefile.

It's a bit dirty, but they do it there - sort of. It's for the boot portion, so it may not be in the "kernel proper".

Have you concidered doing this inside a giagantic "asm" block in a .c file?

The reason this is so uncommon in the kernel, is that the kernel is really meant to be processor independent. So aside for some very select areas, there is little assembly - and when there is - it's all done in "asm" blocks inside .c files.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean arch/x86/boot. I've looked up the make file there, but can't find any mentioning of existing S files.

Comment: no, I really meant i386! (See how infrequently they're used!)

Comment: @yeeeev: you should look for the corresponding `.o` file.

Comment: @ninjalj - I see the corresponding .o files. Does that mean that I simply need to add a corresponding .o file to my .S file? Where's the rule that forces it to be assembled by AS rather then compiled by CC?

Comment: I working with 2.6.34.1 and there's no arch/i386 dir, only x86.

Answer (score -1):

Why would you want to do such a thing besides supporting a new processor ??
You can to the same as `arch/x86/kernel/entry_32.S`.

Nevertheless, I think that you don't have a good reason to add a `.S` file. I'm sure you could do otherwise, it's really not hard to mix C and asm.

The real question you should ask is: "I'm trying to do this... I think about adding a .S file, what do you guys think ?"