# Linkage problems when adding S file to Linux kernel

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel

After a previous question got answered: [Adding a .S file to the linux kernel code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226233/adding-a-s-file-to-the-linux-kernel-code) I was able to add a .S file to the Linux kernel make files.
However, my .S file includes several sections that replace functions that were written in C.
I commented out these functions, and declared the replacement functions as globals, but when I try to link the kernel (using make) I get the following error:

```
arch/x86/kernel/vmlinux.lds:XXX: non constant or forward reference address expression for section .YYY
```

The original functions that I replaced were declared using:
`__attribute__ ((unused, __section__("YYY"))) notrace`

The asm sections are declared using:

```
.text
.globl YYY
```

I also tried adding:

```
.type YYY,@function
```

I probably missed some declaration somewhere, but I'm not sure where to look.

Any ideas?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you coding in asm ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to place assembly functions into section `YYY`, rather than `.text`, you need to replace

```
.text
```

with

```
.section YYY,"ax"
```

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
.text
.globl YYY
```

tells the assembler that you are going to write things in the "text" section, and that "YYY" is a global within that section. Your `.type` adds that "YYY" is the name of a function. That's not what you want: you want the *section* to be named "YYY", not the function itself. To select a section with a specific name, use a `.section` directive (`.text` is just a shortcut for a `.section` which designates the "text" section).